# Using String or Long for Google App Engine Datastore Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the difference of GAE datastore Long id and String key in [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key).

Using the Key

```
KeyFactory.createKey(kind, key);

KeyFactory.createKey(kind, id);
```

So in this case either can be used as Identifier. If I create a Key from `KeyFactory.createKey(kind, key)` where key is a String I can see the `id` field of the key is 0. In this case `getId()` will be `0`? And in contrast, if what is set is `KeyFactory.createKey(kind, someLongValue)` then `getName()` will be a empty `String`?

Comment: Same difference as between an auto generated surrogate ID (Long) or a "natural" business ID (String).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app engine Key can have EITHER a unique long ID, or a unique String name - they are mutually exclusive. If you set a long ID, the name will be null. Which you decide to use for any Entity kind really depends on your use case.

A benefit of using long IDs is that you can have app engine auto-generate them for you. That is, you can create your Entity without any value for its ID, and then when you save it it will be given a valid unique long ID by the datastore.

If you use a String name, you must create the unique name before the Entity is saved. This is useful in some cases if you have some property on the Entity that makes for a natural fit for the unique name (for example, and SKU for a part). Also, some people generate a random UUID for the String name - this ensures that all names are globally unique, not just unique among a particular Entity kind and ancestor path.

Comment: Perhaps just a technicality but I don't agree with your differentiating them by auto-generate capability.  You can auto-generate ID's yourself - I typically do this cause I want access to the ID but don't want to do a synchronous save - and you can then use those ID's as either Long or String id's.  I know this last is a bit unorthodox and I haven't done it myself, but I don't see why not.

Comment: Either longs or Strings let you set the value beforehand. In that case, it is up to you to ensure uniqueness.

However, only Long IDs let you leave the value null, which will then cause AppEngine to auto-generate it on first save. You can't have a String ID that you leave null - app-engine will throw an error when you try to save. Thus, the difference IS that AppEngine will only auto-generate Long IDs, not Strings (and by definition, "auto-generate" means the system does it for you, not the programmer).

Comment: True, I guess 'auto-generate' does mean that.  On the other hand, I think the important thing is that the datastore can generate your id for you - for long or for String.  You are correct about the 'auto' part only applying to long id's, but I haven't found the 'auto' part to be important.